# Pandas Series : faster way of computing periods back to preceding high

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a timeseries of price data stored as Open, High, Low, Close values in a DataFrame

I want to make a new column in which each element records the count of how many days back you need to look to find a high higher in the source array.

So for a series like this

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    my_vals = pd.Series([10.1, 9.0, 2.4, 8.2, 7.0, 6.1, 5.4, 9.4, 8.7, 11.8, 3.5, 4.7, 5.4, 6.4, 7.8, 8.0, 9.1, 10.2, 11.0, 2.0])
```

we would get these values 
[NaN, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 7, 1, NaN, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]

I wrote this code using rolling_apply, which works, but its really really slow and I'm convinced there's probably a far better way to do this.

```
def countDaysSinceHigherHigh(x):
    aaa = pd.Series(x)

    zzz = x[-1] #looking for values higher than zzz
    bbb = aaa[:-1:] #array without last element
    ccc = bbb[bbb>zzz]  #boolean array with elements that are higher than zzz

    ddd = ccc.last_valid_index()
    if ddd == None:
        return np.NaN #or return 10000 to match window length
    else:
        return aaa.last_valid_index() - ddd
```

And then to compute the new column we just do

```
new_col = pd.rolling_apply(my_vals, 10000, countDaysSinceHigherHigh, min_periods = 0 )
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by two for loop, but the worst time complexity maybe `O(N**2)`. Here is a method that can do this in `O(N*log(N))`:

The algorithm:

- `argsort()` the array to get an `index` array
- for every element in `index` at `idx`, find the largest element in `index` after `idx`, that is the largest one less than `idx`. To do this quickly, you can use `SortedList`. Here are two library that implement sorted list:

http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html

http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/sortedlist.html

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

def nearest_hi_value(my_vals):
    index = np.argsort(my_vals)
    sl = SortedList(range(len(index)), load=100)
    res = []
    for idx in index.tolist():
        sl.remove(idx)
        idx2 = sl.bisect_left(idx)
        if idx2 > 0:
            res.append(idx - sl[idx2-1])
        else:
            res.append(0)
    result = np.zeros_like(index)
    result[index] = res
    return result
```

If the two continuous elements in the array is the same, `nearest_hi_value()` may return 1, but this can be fixed easily.

Here is the result check:

```
my_vals = np.random.rand(1000)
res1 = pd.rolling_apply(my_vals, 10000, countDaysSinceHigherHigh, min_periods = 0 )
res2 = nearest_hi_value(my_vals)
np.allclose(res1, res2)
```

Here is the timeit result:

```
%timeit pd.rolling_apply(my_vals, 10000, countDaysSinceHigherHigh, min_periods = 0 )
%timeit nearest_hi_value(my_vals)
```

output:

```
1 loops, best of 3: 489 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: What an outstanding solution! I lay awake last night thinking that something like this must be possible, but I know I wouldnt have come up with this. I was resigned to writing the nested for loop version this morning and then seeing if I could use numba to speed it up. But this is just perfect and its made me aware of these rather cool sortedcontainers into the bargain. Many many many thanks :)

Comment: I think nested for loop with numba will be faster than this solution for normal case and not too large array size. To test the worst case, use a ascending array.